# Elasticsearch null values aggregation, sum beng 0 and avg being null?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch to do analyze and found that when doing the aggregation, if one bucket all elements are null value, the sum result is 0, but avg result is null.

```html
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [ {
                "term" : {
                  "2219" : "AAA"
                }
              }, {
                "term" : {
                  "2219" : "BBB"
                }
              }, {
                "term" : {
                  "2219" : "CCC"
                }
              }, {
                "term" : {
                  "2219" : "DDD"
                }
              } ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "explain" : false,
  "aggregations" : {
    "2224" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "2224",
        "missing" : "null",
        "size" : 2000
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "2219" : {
          "terms" : {
            "field" : "2219",
            "missing" : "null",
            "size" : 2000
          },
          "aggregations" : {
            "a" : {
              "avg" : {
                "field" : "2255"
              }
            },
            "count" : {
              "value_count" : {
                "field" : "1982"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result will be

```html
...
{
  "2219": {           
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
      {
      "key": "DDD",
      "doc_count": 1,
      "a": {
        "value": null
      }
    }
    ]
  },
  "key": "rock",
  "doc_count": 1
}
...
```

The result for "a" is null.

But if I change to sum, the result of "a" is 0.

Weird different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar issue in ES github: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9745

**null** is considered a correct value for AVG aggregation in case when ES has found 0 entities.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this script to the aggregation to remove nulls:

```
"avg" : {
    "field" : "2255"
    "script":{  
        "lang":"painless",
        "source":"if (_value == null) {return 0} else {return _value}"
     }
 }
```